# How to retrieve a correct data from multiple joined db table using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i am working on a cakephp test project, but im stuck for sometime now on getting the information from another table which is not directly related to the present model im retrieving the data.

the scenario is this:(please see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/liFmk.png)
all the green tables are connected to each other, AC  belongsTO {AA, AB}
i have the aa_id.

How can i get the data from table AD using cakephp "find".

ie:

$params = array('conditions' => array('...' => $aa_id));

$this->aa->ab-ac->find('all',$params);

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your controller you will find `var $uses = array(...);`, which contains a list of models immediately available in the controller.  Add 'AD' to the list.  You will then be able to call `$this->AD->find();` anywhere in the controller.

Comment: hmmm.. its not possible because i need to go through the 3 tables in order to get the value from AD